# Cannot get TcpClient to connect to gmail

Tags: c#, tcp, gmail, imap, ioexception

I'm trying to make something that will read email, but I can't get anything to work. This code:

```
TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
c.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993);
NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();
stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
stream.ReadByte();
```

Seams to be where any code I download breaks. The last line throws an IOException with the message: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I would settle for a third party program that automatically downloads email in a format I can read. I have gotten Thunderbird to connect to gmail so the problem is on my end for sure.

Comment: Don't you need to write something to it before you can read something from it?

Comment: @minitech maybe? I tried just writing a zero byte to the stream and it still breaks.

Comment: @nos If I change the timeout to 60 seconds it still breaks.

Comment: @user1820576: No, I mean I think you need to send a valid request that Gmail will respond to. (Just a guess, though - I don't know the specifics of IMAP...)

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting on the SSL port.  If you do not do a proper SSL-handshake, it will close the connection shortly after without sending you any data.

Comment: The message would indicate a disconnect. Also, he is not sending anything.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the remote server did not respond. It did not say "no connection allowed on this port". It did not say "I close the connection". It said nothing.

This means that you are not able to even create a connection on the TCP level. Try this:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

It will fail. So it has nothing to do with you application.

Answer (score 0):

use openssl to connect to gmail. its an easy way to get your things done.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail IMAP uses SSL, so you need to wrap your network stream with `SslStream` and call `AuthenticateAsClient` method (so that it does the SSL handshake/server authentication magic). After that you interact with it as if it's normal (non-SSL) stream:

```
TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
c.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(c.GetStream());
sslStream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("imap.gmail.com");
sslStream.ReadByte();
```